# how to get select option value using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

when I first click button(with drop down list), it shows:

```
    <select name="loginfield" style="float: left; display: none;"         width="45" id="loginfield_LbS4K" change="changetip($('loginfield_LbS4K').value)" selecti="0">
```

I need to get the second value and auto click it .when I choose the second drop down list 
it shows:

```
    <select name="loginfield" style="float: left; display: none;" width="45" id="loginfield_LbS4K" change="changetip($('loginfield_LbS4K').value)" selecti="1">
```

I use python3.6 + selenium ,but I still not get the "second" vaule' foucs(username).it still stop at first foucs(nickname)

```
    el = driver.find_element_by_name('loginfield')
    for option in el.find_elements_by_name('option'):
    print (option)
      if option.value == 'username':
         option.click()
         break
```

please check out where is my wrong , thanks.

---

the html code:

```
</style>
<div class="rfm">
<div id="username_" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="margin: -47px 0 0 130px; display: none;">
<div id="tip_c">login</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<span class="login_slct">
<select name="loginfield" style="float: left;" width="45" id="loginfield_LG388" change="changetip($('loginfield_LG388').value)">
                                            <option value="nickname">account</option>
<option value="username">nickname</option>
<option value="mobile">phone</option>
<option value="email">Email</option>
</select>
</span>
</th>
<td><input type="text" name="username" id="username_LG388" autocomplete="off" size="30" class="px p_fre" tabindex="1" value="" onmouseover="display('username_')" onmouseout="display('username_')" placeholder="login"/></td>
<td class="tipcol"><a href="member.php?mod=register">register</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changetip(v) {
if(v == 'nickname') {
$('tip_c').innerHTML = 'login';
}else if(v == 'mobile') {
$('tip_c').innerHTML = 'phone';
}else if(v == 'username') {
$('tip_c').innerHTML = 'nickname';
}else if(v == 'email') {
$('tip_c').innerHTML = 'email';
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: seems you give wrong HTML code, because the style `display:none` means user can't see it from page, so user how to operate it. Please give the whole HTML code of your dropdown list,

Answer (score 0):

I reckon if you provide the complete HTML code of your select tag, folks over here can debug and give you the right solution. I'm going to take this opportunity and rewrite the code using selenium Select class as I believe it gives a good implementation to work with drop down boxes

See if it helps you

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

el = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('loginfield'))
el.select_by_value('username')
```